# How do I install an R package from zip?

Tags: r

I have read a bunch of questions and sites about installing an R package from a zip, but I cannot get it to work properly.  I am running the command:

```
install.packages("caret_6.0-24.zip", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

It looks like it works, it gives me this repsonse:

```
inferring 'repos = NULL' from the file name
package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

The problem is that after I've installed the package, it doesn't seem to do anything.  For example, I run this command and get the response on the second line.

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = data$class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
Error: could not find function "createDataPartition"
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Do you just need to load the package using library(caret)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used `require` or `library` to load the package?  Installing just downloads and places the files in a specific directory that can be later loaded from.  Try:

```
library(caret)
```

Or

```
require(caret)
```